# Replace all urls in a page with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I need some direction/examples of how to replace all the links in the head of a document using jquery.

I am working with an app that requires my site have an SSL.  My host has a shared SSL that I can use to access my site.  In order to keep from purchasing an SSL, and a static IP (and to just prove I can do it), I am accessing my site securely through their secure URL viewing an html file that is just a frame which is serving up an unsecure page (my site).  I have to access my site securely using their url with their path to my site, so it's something like this - https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/mysite/app/index.html (which is simply a frame with the source pointing at my site).

Anyway, of course there are security warnings as my site is pulling in javascript files and such using http://mysite.com/mysite.js vs. https://secure.bluehost.com~username/mysite/mysite.js.  So, long story short I need to replace all the links in the head of the document from http://mysite.com to https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/mysite.

For example, I wanna change every link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_182/
style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/mysite/wp-
content/themes/thesis_182/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to just edit the source of your site rather than trying to do this client-side with jQuery.

Comment: Would the fact that the script I am going to put into the document is in the page itself make that script insecure too?  Would I need to link to it like this  https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/mysite/app/linkchanger.js?

Comment: I'll check into that.  I could just link to those javascript files and such through my servers secure link, or host them on amazon s3 securely.

Answer (score 2):

Just omit the protocol and use `//`. This will use the current protocol whatever it is..

So change your links to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//mysite.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_182/
style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work, but I didn't tried out:

```
$('link').each(function () {
    var target = $(this);
    var oldHref = target.attr('href');
    var newHreh = oldHref.replace('http://mysite.com', 'https://secure.bluehost.com/~username/mysite');
    target.attr('href', newHref);
});
```

To let the code before it's too late, thus before the css is loaded on the page, simply don't put the  tag in the header, but put it, for example, at the end of the page.
You can also omit the  tag declaration and approach the problem in a different way, adding to the body tag the link tag with the right address using jQuery.

Comment: How do you ensure that this runs before the browser attempts to load the CSS files?